# Why am I getting a SLF4J Error when I'm not using it?

Tags: java, eclipse, slf4j

I have a small single-class Java project in Eclipse that does not use any form of logging. I have another project that uses SLF4J open in the same workspace.

When I run my program, it outputs to STDOUT and takes Scanner input from STDIN, but following successful completion of the program, I get this printed to STDERR:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

If SLF4J is not included in my project (it's not a maven dependency either), why is it showing this error?

Comment: it is definitively starting slf4j, probably it is in the classpath.... check the start configuration..

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Kind of hard to know how you are executing this program, how your project is  set up, ... "Launch Configuration" can be found at Menu: Run > Run Configurations...

Comment: It's running as a Java application. Where in the configuration window can I find SLF4J being imported?

Comment: Run mvn dependency:tree and see what is using slf4j ;)

Comment: Ah, it's a component of pdfbox. How can I turn that off? (sorry for all the questions!)

Comment: It depends on which binding is being used. Take a look at the [slf4j manual](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a dependency or a transitive dependency on the classpath that uses the slf4j logging api. Slf4j is setup in such a manner that when loaded it expects you to also be supplying an implementation.

In the simplest setup, you could add slf4j-simple as a dependency of your project to provide the expected implementation. It will log all messages to the console.  If you choose to not add an implementation all that will happen is that you will not see any logs from that library.

If this is a personal project it may not be important unless you need to debug an issue.

If this is an existing project for production there are a couple things you can do depending on the circumstances.

- You can start using slf4j for your logging with logback-classic
- If you are already using a different logger like log4j you can add a jar that routes the slf4j logging to your existing logger (Refer to slf4j [manual](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) for specific details on your logger)
- You can supply your own logging implementation (Refer to slf4j [manual](https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html) for details on doing this.

Comment: Since this is a small, single class project, I don't want to go through the hassle of setting up logging. Is there any way I can suppress the message without adding a bridge/binding?

Comment: Nope. It makes calls directly to System.err if it cant find an implementation. You can add a simpler implementation such as slf4j-simple(which only logs to console) or slf4j-nop(which effectively gets rid of the message), but you gotta add something to not see the message.